# Getting data from a table to ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection, connection-string

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to build an ASP.NET web application, I'm working on dynamically populating (part) of the site map from information in a database. Right now I just have a dummy table in my App_Data folder, called DrugTest.mdf. The table is just called DrugTest1, which only has one field, DrugName. Where I'm hitting a wall is actually getting the data out of that table. Part of what I'm confused about is the connection string. I've looked at a lot of different information about connection strings, most notably http://www.connectionstrings.com/ but I'm a little confused as to how to actually apply said information to this project.

EDIT: I'm using SQL Server 2008 RC.

For example: `Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

Password and User Id are pretty self-explanatory, but as far as I know I didn't get either one of those, I just added a table to the App_Data folder and filled it with dummy data. ServerAddress is a little confusing, because this information isn't really stored on a server, it's just stored locally. And I'm honestly not sure what Initial Catalog means.
Here's the code to populate the sub-tree. You'll notice the connection string is left blank.

```
string connString = ""; // get the connection string
string commandString = "SELECT drugName FROM DrugTable1";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString); // connect to db
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection); // set up the command
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet drugs = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(drugs);

foreach (DataRow row in drugs.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string drugName = row["Name"] + "";
    SiteMapNode node = new SiteMapNode(this, drugName,
                        "~/PlaceHolderUrl?path=" + drugName,
                        drugName);
    AddNode(node, root);
}
```

Furthermore, I've got a nagging suspicion that I'm not going about this the right way. I think this will be the proper implementation once the database is up and running, but for right now I just want to get it working so it's ready to go - just slap in the proper connection string and table/field names.

So, finally, my question(s): How would I go about connecting to this local table? What format should my connection string be? I noticed there's a lot of them. Is there a better way to do this/am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Loading database files by connection string is a pain. My advice would be to just download and install SQL Express edition and use that. It's far closer to what your intended target environment is and doesn't cost anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of getting the right connection string check this out in the ServerExplorer window

- On the Menu click on View->Server Explorer
- In the Server Explorer window locate DrugTest.mdf
- Right click the file and select Properties

[image]

- You can see the right connection string in the properties
- Copy the connection string and use

Note: that the file location was hard-coded. You might need to use `|DataDirectory|` later

Comment: I have been looking for that specific thing for three days now. I was looking for it in this App_Data\DrugTest.mdf folder. I feel like an idiot, but thanks so much, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the Initial Catalog portion of your connection string with `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DrugTest.mdf`.

Also, if you're using SQL Server Express, you might need to include the instance in the Data Source, so might try `Data Source=mySeverAddress\SQLExpress`, where SQLExpress is the instance name.

BTW, at the http://www.connectionstrings.com site, you can find this information in the SQL Server 2008 page if you scroll down a bit to the section titled "Attach a database file, located in the data directory, on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance."

Comment: So I should just leave the user name and password blank?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
`Thrown by adapter.Fill(drugs)`

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're using the full version of SQL Server and not SQLExpress, so change the Data Source back to just myServerAddress.

Comment: I completely missed that entry on connectionstrings. Thanks for pointing it out.